# 22.04 crash after nvidia driver install

Tags: nvidia

I did not install "additional drivers" during the Ubuntu install process. Now that the graphics crash (weird overlays and only the app in the foreground is accessible) every second day I thought it might be the missing nvidia drivers for my DELL 9700. Via "Software Updater" > "Addistional drivers" I installed the nvidia drivers and now upon reboot this screen is all I get. How do I delete those drivers from there? Thanks

[image]